# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Host should not be empty at proxy in expressjs

Tags: mongodb, typescript, express

i am trying to run expressjs project it's shows errors like
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Host should not be empty at proxy (/../../Desktop/folder/myproject/node_modules/express-http-proxy/index.js:27:3)
  {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: undefined,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! authentication@1.0.0 start: `./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc; node main`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the authentication@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/folder/.npm/_logs/2020-01-01T07_03_08_044Z-debug.log

Comment: did you find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Your app is using proxy from express-http-proxy, proxy is supposed to take first argument as a value. That value is missing or undefined.

Check all the occurrence of proxy function inside your app and find the missing argument, most probably you have defined that value and taken from .env file but it's not define inside .env file.